# build Libidn for Apple TV

Tags: objective-c, xmpp, tvos, xmppframework, apple-tv

I am working in chat application for Apple TV. and am using https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.

Its working in simulator but not in Apple TV.
Am getting error message,

ld: in /Users/c/Documents/Kasi/v-appletv/vertv/XMPP/Vendor/libidn/libidn.a(nfkc.o), building for tvOS, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

how to build libidn for tvOS?

Comment: Its working, i have changed sdk version, path and platform name as AppleTVOS in build-libdidn.sh file. finally successfully run in Apple TV :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried downloading [libidn](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libidn/) and compiling the library for tvOS ?

I don't really know how to compile for tvOS, but [this](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/CompilingLibidn) should give a clue.
You need to use the AppleTVOS.platform instead of iPhoneOS.platform of course and maybe change some other values too.

Comment: Thanks for your response. yeah i tried. but its not working. can you share how to compile libidn for tvOS

Comment: Sorry, don't really know, but checkout https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/CompilingLibidn

Comment: it support only in Xcode 4.x series, because Xcode version >5 does not have llvm-gcc compiler.